# osx - Keyboard shortcut to cycle between Preview windows

Tags: macos

`cmd+'` cycles between windows for every app but Preview, is there any other way to configure this?

`ctrl+F4` does cycle through Preview, but I would like to cycle only through Preview windows, as `cmd+'` works.

By the way, I'm on OS X 10.6.8

Comment: This should work. Did you create custom keyboard shortcuts specific to Preview (*System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Applications*)? Are any third party keyboard shortcut utilities (Quicksilver, LaunchBar, Alfred, Butler, …) running? Does it work if you quit them? Create a new user account and try to see whether the shortcut works there?

Comment: Custom Shortcuts asks for a specific menu item, which as far as I've checked, there is none for cycling windows. And I don't use any of the tools mentioned.